# Mostrar null o valor por defecto al traer una consulta sin resultados

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Me gustaría poder traer un valor por defecto después de ejecutar una consulta en caso de que no traiga ninguna fila. He intentado de todo un poco, COALESCE, NULLIF, NOT EXISTS, EXISTS, etc.

No se si de pronto alguien ya lo ha intentado antes para ver si me podría hacer el favor de ayudarme con esto.

SQL:

```
SELECT  CASE 
        WHEN  EXISTS(SELECT tabla1.tbl1_campo1 
                    FROM tabla1
                    WHERE tabla1.campo2 = 'EXAMPLE' 
                    AND tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1_tbl1 )  THEN '1'::CHAR(1)
        ELSE '0'::CHAR(1)
    END
    FROM    tabla2, tabla3
    WHERE   tabla2.campo1 = 138239
    AND     tabla2.campo1_tbl3 = tabla3.campo1
    AND     (split_part(tabla3.campo2, '-', 1))::CHAR(2) IN ('16', '17', '18')
```

Si la ejecuto así como está, me trae como resultado cero filas y me gustaría que por lo menos mostrara una fila/campo, (definida por mi), para poder hacer un comparativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano, toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar con el asunto, ya que llevo varios días tratando de buscar una respuesta a este problema y aún no he podido encontrarla.

Comment: ahh.. es que si la consulta trae cero filas, no importa lo que hagas sobre el select, siempre van a ser cero filas...

Comment: Ooouch, ¿pero no hay ni tan si quiera una remota posibilidad de poder agregar un NULL o un valor por defecto cuando eso suceda?.

Comment: y no.. sobre que la quieres agregar.. no se el contexto sobre el cual estas usando esto.. tal vez la respuesta sea mas simple si agregas donde estas y a donde quieres llegar...

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Básicamente ese ejemplo de query es un Subquery de una gran consulta, lo que necesito es dejar un valor cuando traiga datos con esas especificaciones que le doy.

Comment: bueno, sin mas informacion no podria ayudarte.. podria decirte que le agregues un union con un query que devuelva siempre 1 fila, pero tampoco te va a servir, pq si la consulta devolvio algo, agrega un registro de mas.. tambien podria decirte que lo chequees en tu SP, pero no se si estas trabajando alli dentro...

Comment: Gracias por el dato, ya intenté lo del JOIN de múltiples formas y no funcionó, siempre enviaba un error, y lo de SP no lo entendí, me podrías hacer el favor de explicarme que es, gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 2):

Podría hacerse con `UNION ALL`. Sólo que, en el segundo SELECT deben haber tantas columnas como en el primero, de lo contrario no funcionará.

### EDIT

Ahora debe funcionar...

**<kbd>[Ver DEMO en REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/DOQFO29877)</kbd>**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_NULL (
   ID_TEST     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NOMBRE      CHAR (50)              NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TEST_NULL (NOMBRE) VALUES ('Test 1'), ('Test 2');

-- Prueba 1

SELECT ID_TEST, 
       NOMBRE, 
       1 AS TMP_ID 
FROM TEST_NULL 
WHERE ID_TEST>=0
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,
       NULL,
       1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST_NULL WHERE ID_TEST >= 0);


-- Prueba 2

SELECT ID_TEST, 
       NOMBRE, 
       1 AS TMP_ID 
FROM TEST_NULL 
WHERE ID_TEST = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,
       NULL,
       1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST_NULL WHERE ID_TEST = 1);

-- Prueba 3

SELECT ID_TEST, 
       NOMBRE, 
       1 AS TMP_ID 
FROM TEST_NULL 
WHERE ID_TEST = 3
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,
       NULL,
       1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST_NULL WHERE ID_TEST = 3);
```

**Resultados**

*Prueba 1*

```
    id_test       nombre    tmp_id
1   1             Test 1    1
2   2             Test 2    1
```

*Prueba 2*

```
    id_test       nombre    tmp_id
1   1             Test 1    1
```

*Prueba 3*

```
    id_test       nombre    tmp_id
1   NULL          NULL      1
```

Comment: si pero esto devuelve una fila de mas cuando el resultado sea valido y devuelva filas.. fijate en los comentarios.

Comment: Pero igual me da una idea de como puedo traer la info, para poder traer SIEMPRE una sola fila, yo lo que haría sería ponerle al final un LIMIT 1 y eso me solucionaría el problema, por ese lado por lo menos.

Comment: @ManuelCaicedo Prueba ahora, he editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las sentencias `WITH`.

```
-- ajustar los nombres de campos, tablas y condiciones a tus necesidades
with cte_datos as ( -- Consulta principal
  select id, valor from mitabla
  where cond = 999999
)

select id, valor from cte_datos  -- Obtiene los datos de la consulta principal
union all
select 0, 'N/A' -- Obtiene los valores por defecto
  where not exists (select * from cte_datos) -- siempre que no haya registros en la consulta principal
```