# Query que devuelva NULL o un valor 'X' si no encuentra resultados con SELECT

Tags: mysql

necesito ayuda en `MySQL`; necesito hacer un `SELECT` que, si no encuentra resultados, devuelva un valor `NULL` o bien un `0`, he buscado en Google, pero no encuentro nada que me sirva.

La consulta que tengo es:

```
SELECT empleado_id FROM tabla_empleados WHERE RUT = '123456789';
```

La idea es que devuelva un resultado `NULL` o `0` si no encuentra el registro `123456789`.

Comment: Estás utilizando MySQL o Microsoft SQL Server? La sintaxis es distinta.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio no es una base de datos. Es una ide para conectar a sql server..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los tags son importantes para que entendamos de que estas hablando. Y aca generan confusion.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75088/mostrar-null-o-valor-por-defecto-al-traer-una-consulta-sin-resultados

Comment: @SoftMolina esa es sobre postgres... que nada que ver con myslq o sql server :(

Comment: Tulpa asi no funciona el sitio. Tu pregunta debe ser clara y no podes andar cambiandola a cada rato segun te convenga. La gente que te respondio se tomo el trabajo de tratar de entenderla, aunque no contestaste uno solo de los comentarios que se te hicieron, y fuiste cambiando la pregunta a cada rato, dejando respuestas que eran validas como invalidas y viceversa. Si tenes otra pregunta, hacela. Lee los enlaces que te pase para entender como funciona el sitio. Por favor, no vuelvas a editar tu pregunta y cambiar todo el sentido.

Comment: Tambien, no debes contestar tu propia pregunta dentro de la pregunta. Si tenes una respuesta a tu propia pregunta (y ninguna de las que hay sirvio, y de ser el caso aclara a quien te respondio porque no sirvio), hacelo en la seccion respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que agregar una fila con un nulo para que la regrese en caso de que no haya valores.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT empleado_id FROM tabla_empleados WHERE RUT = '123456789'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL) x
ORDER BY empleado_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder condicionar el resultado nulo, debes hacer uso de la función **ISNULL**:

La cuál recibe 2 parámetros, el primero a evaluar si es nulo o no, y el segundo la respuesta en caso de que el parámetro evaluado sea nulo.

```
SELECT ISNULL(empleado_id, '') FROM tabla_empleados WHERE RUT = '123456789';
```

Saludos.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es correcta, es solo correcta si el motor es sql server.. si no seria ifnull... por lo tanto, hubiera sido mejor esperar ese minutito a que OP definiera bien de que esta hablando. Se supone que como usa SSMS estaria usando sql server.. pero bueno...

Comment: @gbianchi pero la respuesta no está correcta según lo que quiere el op

Comment: @Lamak ah tenes razon.. me centre tanto en corregir todo lo mal que esta todo en la pregunta (y las respuestas, me refiero a las formas) que no me di cuenta que esta consulta no devuelve nada de nada :(

Comment: la pregunta al comienzo decía específicamente Sql Server, ahora está corregida y de paso indica que es MySql... gracias por el (-1).

Comment: @Rostan de nada. Pero la respuesta estaba mala para SQL Server, por eso el voto negativo

Answer (score 0):

Con un if sale.
se que hace doble busqueda, pero para una tabla pequeña funciona.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM tabla_empleados WHERE RUT = '123456789')
BEGIN
    SELECT empleado_id FROM tabla_empleados WHERE RUT = '123456789'
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT NULL
END
```

Comment: no tarde ni 2 segundos en editar y ya me estan difamando xD

Comment: OP cambio a mysql, ahora la respuesta directamente esta mal :(

Comment: @gbianchi op volvió a cambiar a SQL Server :/

Comment: @Lamak la volvi atras..